# Is there a way to search sphinx documentation from slack?

Tags: python-sphinx, slack-api, slack

Is there a good way, bot or library on how to have a `/search` command in Slack that would look up through Sphinx-generated documentation?

Alternatively, is there a library for searching (inter)sphinx, or do I have to tear it out of sphinx core?

Comment: I thought you can just open the document and use the search box? I don't quite understand your issue.

Comment: @xuhdev I want to be able to do that search from slack to skip the open & click step